# Retrieve values in $.ajax

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax

I would like retrieve my object values in $.ajax.

My web Service method Statistic_1 return an Object1 that has an array of object2 .

In C# code, I retrieve in this manner: Object1.Items[0].Name for example.

Items is a porperty of my Object1 that is an array of object2.

Here is my JavaScript code :

```
function getStatistic1() {

  var response;
  var allstat1 = [];

  $.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: 'http://localhost:52768/Service1/Statistic_1',
   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function (msg) {
            response = msg.d;
            for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {

                  allstat1[i] =**???**

            }

            fillData(allstat1);

    },
    error: function (e) {
    alert("error loading statistic 1");
    }
  })
}

function fillData(data) {

   $('#table_campaigns').dataTable({
        **???**
   });
}
```

how to implement to retrieve the values?

**Edit :**
@RoyiNamir, @Tom Cammann
Here is my code in Service.cs

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    ResponseStatistic_1 Statistic_1();
```

ResponseStatistic_1 class

```
public class ResponseStatistic_1 : IBaseClientEntity
{
    public ResponseStatistic_1()
    {

    }

    public ResponseStatistic_1(Statistic_1 [] items) : this()
    {
        this.Items = items;
    }

    #region Properties
    public Statistic_1[] Items
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

And Statistic_1 is class

```
public class Statistic_1
{
    private string _geografisch_zone;
    private decimal[] _sum; 
    private int _yearStart;
    private int _yearEnd;

             ...
}
```

How I implement the for loop?

Comment: How does your json looks like ?

Comment: What does the response object look like?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read multi-level Json data by using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456887/how-to-read-multi-level-json-data-by-using-jquery)

Comment: @RoyiNamir and TomCammann I put the code in answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your response object...

If it's an array you are returning:

```
function successFunction(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $('#table_campaigns').dataTable().fnAddData(data[i])
    }      
}
```

Your ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: 'http://localhost:52768/Service1/Statistic_1',
   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
   dataType: 'json',
   success: successFunction,
    error: function (e) {
    alert("error loading statistic 1");
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: I don't understand because I don't think that is an array I'm returning. This is an object that has an array of an other object. I put the code in answer.

Comment: I tried this : response = msg.Items. But response is null, why? However, in my WCFTestClient.exe, the method Statistic_1 works well.